# How to include png as backgound image without downloading anything else than HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am generating one html file. The file should display 3 divs. Each div will have:

```
background-image: url("something.png");
```

Now, when user will download the file (e.g. chooses  "save page as"), he will only get the HTML - without the actual `png` file.

How can I make sure that he is able to see them, without making him download them?

I've tried converting to SVG, but this pictures have multiple colors, and it totally failed.

Comment: What problem as you trying to solve? Are you trying to make a page that people can save in its entirety?

Comment: @Quentin The problem is, when you download a webpage as HTML, you get no images, but just text.

Comment: @nicael — In most browsers you solve that by selecting "Webpage, Complete" in the Save As dialogue.

Comment: There are multiple workarounds for this issue check out this article naturefocused.com/articles/image-protection.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just make it data-based, i.e.

```
background:url(data:image/png;base64,base64-encoded-image-goes-here)
```

It is possible to have jpg, gif, etc.

You can get the base64 image by using an image-to-base64 converter.

Comment: can you be more specific? should i use background:url(data:something.png) ?

Comment: @uksz Yep, a second.

Comment: @nicael this is still downloading an image, just in a different format, is it not the same? Forgive my ignorance on the subject, I am of the impression that base64 encoding an image just increases the size but removes the need to refer to the file.

Comment: @N.J.Dawson Exactly, OP's aim is " when user will download the file, he will only get the HTML - without the actual png file." This solution workarounds that limit.

Comment: @nicael ah, that's me being dense then, I had misunderstood the question. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @nicael, it works great. I would edit your answer, and mention that someone needs to actually convert the png to the base-64 ;)

Comment: @uksz Since it worked, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: There are multiple workarounds for this issue check out this article http://www.naturefocused.com/articles/image-protection.html

Comment: @Amir Comment  not under my answer, but under the question :)